# Recieving 404 error when running get request to Amadeus low-fare-search API

Tags: amadeus

Hi I am very new to Angular and programming in general and I have been trying to query the Amadeus low-fare-search with Angular `HTTPClient` and failing, I have been looking around for answers, but havent found anything specific to this, I have found some answers related to the specific problem of "unable to identify proxy".

And according to some the reason for this is that the URL is incorrect. 
But this is the URL on Amadeus page

[Resource URL](https://api.sandbox.amadeus.com/v1.2/flights/low-fare-search)

This is the code i am trying to run :

```
search(){
    return this.http.get('http://api.sandbox.amadeus.com/v1.2/flights/low-fare-search?origin=IST&destination=BOS&departure_date=2018-10-15&return_date=2018-10-21&number_of_results=3&apikey=my API key')
    .subscribe((data) =>{
        console.log(data)},
        (err) => {console.log(err)});
```

Here is the error message

> errorcode: "messaging.adaptors.http.flow.ApplicationNotFound"
>   faultstring:"Unable to identify proxy for host: default and url:
>   /v1.2/flights/low-fare-search"

Can someone explain to me in simple terms what could be causing this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, you are using **http** instead of **https**

I tested your example and it works for me:

> https://api.sandbox.amadeus.com/v1.2/flights/low-fare-search?origin=IST&destination=BOS&departure_date=2018-10-15&return_date=2018-10-21&number_of_results=3&apikey={your_api_key}

Comment: Thank you Anthony will try this as soon as i get time :)

Comment: For your information the Travel Innovation Sandbox will be decommissioned in the coming months. The new portal to access the APIs is [Amadeus for Developers](http://developers.amadeus.com). Could be worth it for you to invest time in the new version instead of the old one.

Comment: thank you for the info greatly appreciated. Tried to register but it seemed there were some server issue though.

Comment: Everything should be up and running! If you face any issue please contact us at developers@amadeus.com